# $(document).on('click' is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the simple code which I am trying on js fiddle:

```
<select id="test">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option class="pid">1</option>
  <option class="pid">2</option>
  <option class="pid">3</option>
  <option class="pid">4</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.pid', function () {
       alert('here');
    });
});
```

Click on http://jsfiddle.net/QRVSw/16/

Comment: The whole idea about `$(document).on` is that you can call it at any time, and you don't have to wrap in in a jQuery ready function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event applies to the whole `select` element, not to the individual options. Also it's better to use the `change` event which triggers *after* making a selection, in contrast to the `click` event, which triggers as soon as you click.

In addition, you don't need to wrap your code to prepare it for OnReady. With this `on` call, you bind the event to the document, which is already available, even if the select object itself isn't yet.

So, your code could be simplified (and made working) like this:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#test', function () {
   alert('here');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make use of the `onchange` event for select elements:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#test', function () {
       alert('here');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option class="pid">1</option>
  <option class="pid">2</option>
  <option class="pid">3</option>
  <option class="pid">4</option>
</select>
```